# React highlight and slice long text

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Let's image I have a long text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

I've entered letter `s` and a lot of letters of these text got highlighted. I want to slice it and show highlighted letters.

I use `react-native-highlight-words` to highlight the words. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highlight-words

In docs there's a sanitize method, but I'm not sure how can it be used?
`Sanitize - Process each search word and text to highlight before comparing (eg remove accents); signature (text: string): string`

Here's the example:

[image]

Here's a piece of my code:

```
  <Highlighter
    highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
    searchWords={[searchWords]}
    textToHighlight={description}
  />
```

What's the best approach to achieve it?

Comment: Any code you have achieved?

Comment: @keikai Just attached

Comment: It doesn't look like that library supports anything more than the behavior you've described it already doing. Sanitize looks like it does the opposite of what you're looking for - it processes highlighted text, not the other stuff you want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above library (react-native-highlight-words) you will only highlight the text. But to get the highlighted character you will need to pull out the words using regex

Working Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/graceful-blueberries

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textSearch: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
      higightedTexts:''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.findSearchedText()

  }

  findSearchedText(){
    var regex = RegExp("s");
    var wordList = this.state.textSearch.split(" ").filter((elem, index)=>{
        return regex.test(elem);
    })

    this.setState({
      higightedTexts:wordList 
    })
  }

  viewForSearchedText(){
    var array = []
    for(var i=0; i<=this.state.higightedTexts.length; i++){
      var b = <View><Text>{this.state.higightedTexts[i]}</Text></View>
      array.push(b)
    }
    return array
  }






  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
          searchWords={['s']}
          textToHighlight= {this.state.textSearch}
        />
        <View>
          <Text style={{color:'green', marginTop:20}}>Higlighted Texts</Text>
          {
            this.viewForSearchedText()
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: Wow, looks good! Thanks!

Just one question, is it possible to pull out not the words, but phrases? In your example: 
...psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... or smth like this..

Comment: you will have to write your own regex for it

Comment: Do you have any examples of similar RegExp?

Comment: you will have to write in accordance with your expected result. I can only give a try as i don't know what exactly you want.

Give example of words and what u want to pull from it

Comment: So, I want to display a few highlighted words + a few nearby words.
```
Example: 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat

Output: consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```
The input string contains a lot of highlighted letters and I don't want to display them all to a user, I need to output just a sentence, containing some words with letters highlighted. Hope this will help!

Comment: I think you won't require regex. You can use split and find indexOf
Working Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/bad-watermelon

Comment: Thanks, but in case there are duplicated words the algorithm isn't working as expected:
https://snack.expo.io/HWIM!8sgO

In such case I want to display just 1 sentence with this word:
The Rodrigues starling (Necropsar rodericanus) is an extinct species of starling that was endemic to the Mascarene island of Rodrigues

Comment: I have just shown you the approach you can use the regex also.

Comment: If you want to display only one result then after first result break the loop. Updated the example